# How do I solve Whitelabel Error Page in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have followed the official  [files and package structure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code) of spring boot in my application. But I am still getting a whitelabel page error.

[image]

Below is how I have put my codes and the Image of how files and folders are arranged.

**Controller**

```
 @Controller
 public class UserController  { 
 @RequestMapping("/")
 public String index(HttpServletRequest request){
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
    return  "homepage";
}}
```

**homepage.jsp**

```
<body>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${mode=='MODE_HOME'}">
<h1>Mambo, this is home page </h1>
</c:when> </c:choose>
</body>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>  
<scope>provided</scope>     
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>jstl</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

I have spent the whole day trying to figure out what I am missing with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` to define which routes do not require authentication:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                // add more matches here
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added the class as suggested still getting whitelabel page error

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` ?